# how to display decimal precision value in jasper report 4.0.2

Tags: jasper-reports, openerp-7

i am print a value in jasper report but it's not display decimal precision.

but display value this type 20.00000000 
and i need a Only "20.00" decimal precision

how to solve it
please replay

Comment: It will be fine if you tell us about your datasource

Answer (score 6):

You can try the below expression

```
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{FieldValue})
```

Hope this should solve your problem

Comment: Failed to invoke method execute in class com.nantic.jasperreports.JasperServer: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{Unit_Price-price_unit})

Comment: <textField>
    <reportElement x="320" y="3" width="70" height="14"/>
     <textElement>
      <font pdfEncoding="Cp1254"/>
  </textElement>
  <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{Unit_Price-price_unit}))]]>                   </textFieldExpression>
</textField>

Comment: Try removing one extra brace in your xml

Comment: <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{Unit_Price-price_unit})]]> </textFieldExpression>

Comment: Report Error

Failed to invoke method execute in class com.nantic.jasperreports.JasperServer: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : Float.valueOf($F{Taxes-amount_tax})

Answer (score 3):

Try with this entry into jasper file:

```
<textField pattern="###0.00;(###0.00)">
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{percentage_rate}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Second approach is via java code: Convert the value in 2 decimal place in java file that will be fetched by jasper file.

```
String percentage_rate = new BigDecimal(p_rate!=null ?p_rate:"0").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using field pattern property(right click on field) and use pattern style according to your requirement.

right click on field ->field pattern ->(Category)Number ->you can chose the decimal places.

using ireport IDE
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below on your textfield you would like to format in decimal places i.e .00 formats it into two decimal places. to add more decimal places add the number of zeros eg .000 3 decimal places, .0000 4 decimal places etc

```
<textField  pattern="#,##0.00">
   <textFieldExpression>
      <![CDATA[$P{amount}]]>
   </textFieldExpression>   
</textField>
```